# How do I use multiple WHERE clause in parameterized SQL query?

Tags: java, sql

I have a repository where I want current month records alone to display for the passed User object parameter . This is the query that I have but it is not compiling .

**Repository**

```
@Query("select sum(investment.principal) from Investment investment where MONTH(investment.startDate) = MONTH(CURDATE()) "
            + "AND YEAR(investment.startDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) join investment.customer_id.marketer marketer where marketer = :marketer ")
    BigDecimal getMarketerMonthlyInflow(User marketer);
```

This is the compilation error I am getting

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: join near line 1, column 188 [select sum(investment.principal) from com.bethsaida.org.models.Investment investment where MONTH(investment.startDate) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(investment.startDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) join investment.customer_id.marketer where markter = :marketer ]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.1.Final.jar:5.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.1.Final.jar:5.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:288) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.1.Final.jar:5.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:187) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.1.Final.jar:5.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.1.Final.jar:5.2.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.1.Final.jar:5.2.1.Final]
```

Comment: Show us the compilation error. Instead of where try on

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli I have added the compilation error

Comment: isnt it supposed to be `JOIN SomeOtherTable t ON xyzField`?   I only see a field..

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhahani it is not duplicate , they are totally different

Comment: Your sql statement is incorrect. Search for how to do joins between tables. If you do proper join, then you can have one where with AND separating the different expressions(if this is what you want).

Comment: How many entities are there? three? investment, customer, marketer?

Answer (score 3):

In sql JOIN clause is before WHERE clause. Also joins work with keyword ON, not where.

I can't give you correct query without knowing table columns, use case, etc., but it should look something like that:

```
SELECT SUM(investment.principal) 
FROM Investment investment 
JOIN investment.customer_id.marketer ON markter = :marketer
WHERE MONTH(investment.startDate) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
AND YEAR(investment.startDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Comment: This is what I am getting "SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'user2_.id' in 'on clause'"

Comment: The message makes it look as if your user entity does not have column `id` to make the join.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it :

```
     @Query("select sum(investment.principal) from Investment investment JOIN investment.customer_id.marketer "
            + "marketer ON marketer_id = :marketer WHERE MONTH(investment.startDate) = MONTH(CURDATE()) "
            + "AND YEAR(investment.startDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())")
    BigDecimal getMarketerMonthlyInflow(User marketer);
```